# Losing layout and styling when i set vaadin productionMode = true

Tags: vaadin

When I set productionMode = true in my Vaadin 7 application the layout and styling is lost any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

the solution was to comment in `<goal>compile-theme</goal>`

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
                <webappDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets</webappDirectory>
                <draftCompile>false</draftCompile>
                <compileReport>false</compileReport>
                <style>OBF</style>
                <strict>true</strict>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update-theme</goal>
                        <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <!-- disabled by default to use on-the-fly theme compilation -->
                        <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: You could also compile the theme yourself and package the resulting file, which will also lower the loading times a bit, as [on the fly compilation may take some time and that's why it's available by default only the `VaadinServlet` is in development mode](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/themes.compiling.html).